# Use or include external schema in search_path on Redshift

Tags: psql, redshift

## Narrative

I have a sql script that creates a bunch of tables in a temporary schema name in Redshift. I don't want to repeat the schema name a bunch of times, so I would like to do something like the following at the top of the script:

```
use long_external_schema_name;
```

My understanding is that Redshift (inheriting from Postgres), you would do:

```
set search_path to '$user', public, long_external_schema_name;
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  External schema "long_external_schema_name" cannot be set in search_path
```

Because, it is an **external schema**.

## Question

Is there any equivalent way that I could stay DRY and write the external schema name only once while I create a bunch of tables in it?

## More Context

Note, I know I have lots of options in bash (arguments, sed, vim, etc) to replace the schema name in the script, but I'm trying to do something more native to Redshift / psql.